# How to parse codeml output in a structured format?

Tags: python

After computing codeml,I had the final output in a text file. Can someone help me out how to parse the output based on new line character **\n**.

I had thousands of ID's which starts with a **prefix** (OG*) (ex - OG*******_M0).

**Input**

```
 \n
OG0022519_M0
lnL = -334.227266
lnL = -334.227266
lnL = -321.454615
lnL = -325.325316
....
....
....
....
Model: One dN/dS ratio for branches,
 Nei & Gojobori 1986. dN/dS (dN, dS)
 t= 0.0228  S=    33.6  N=   245.4  dN/dS=  0.1244  dN = 0.0041  dS = 0.0331
 t= 0.0228  S=    33.6  N=   245.4  dN/dS=  0.1244  dN = 0.0041  dS = 0.0331
 t= 0.0000  S=    31.7  N=   247.3  dN/dS=  0.0010  dN = 0.0000  dS = 0.0000
 t= 0.0000  S=    31.1  N=   247.9  dN/dS=  0.0010  dN = 0.0000  dS = 0.0000
 t= 0.0228  S=    33.6  N=   245.4  dN/dS=  0.1244  dN = 0.0041  dS = 0.0331
 ......
 ......
 ......
 t= 0.0000  S=    27.4  N=   251.6  dN/dS=  2.0000  dN = 0.0000  dS = 0.0000
 t= 0.0119  S=    33.2  N=   245.8  dN/dS=  0.0010  dN = 0.0000  dS = 0.0331
 t= 0.0109  S=    31.4  N=   247.6  dN/dS= 99.0000  dN = 0.0041  dS = 0.0000
 t= 0.0109  S=    31.4  N=   247.6  dN/dS= 99.0000  dN = 0.0041  dS = 0.0000
 t= 0.0119  S=    33.2  N=   245.8  dN/dS=  0.0010  dN = 0.0000  dS = 0.0331

\n
OG0022510_M0
lnL = -389.618240
lnL = -403.414349
lnL = -396.165769
lnL = -430.934701
lnL = -428.190811
lnL = -438.314006
lnL = -430.934701
lnL = -428.190811
.....
.....
.....
Model: One dN/dS ratio for branches,
 Nei & Gojobori 1986. dN/dS (dN, dS)
 t= 0.0216  S=    55.1  N=   247.9  dN/dS=  0.0010  dN = 0.0000  dS = 0.0394
 t= 0.0429  S=    54.9  N=   248.1  dN/dS=  0.0689  dN = 0.0041  dS = 0.0601
 t= 0.0207  S=    56.8  N=   246.2  dN/dS=  0.2171  dN = 0.0041  dS = 0.0189
 t= 0.1162  S=    64.3  N=   238.7  dN/dS=  0.0257  dN = 0.0043  dS = 0.1665
 t= 0.1022  S=    64.3  N=   238.7  dN/dS=  0.0296  dN = 0.0043  dS = 0.1445
 ......
 ......
 ......
 ......

 t= 0.1253  S=    62.8  N=   240.2  dN/dS=  0.0505  dN = 0.0085  dS = 0.1688
 t= 0.1162  S=    64.3  N=   238.7  dN/dS=  0.0257  dN = 0.0043  dS = 0.1665
 t= 0.1022  S=    64.3  N=   238.7  dN/dS=  0.0296  dN = 0.0043  dS = 0.1445
 t= 0.1253  S=    62.8  N=   240.2  dN/dS=  0.0505  dN = 0.0085  dS = 0.1688
 t= 0.0000  S=    70.0  N=   233.0  dN/dS=  0.0010  dN = 0.0000  dS = 0.0000
 t= 0.1162  S=    64.3  N=   238.7  dN/dS=  0.0257  dN = 0.0043  dS = 0.1665
 t= 0.1022  S=    64.3  N=   238.7  dN/dS=  0.0296  dN = 0.0043  dS = 0.1445
```

I wouldd like to parse the text file into a **tabular format**.

**Expected output -**

```
ID              InL                  t       S           N        dN/dS             dN              dS  
OG0022519_M0 lnL = -334.227266    t= 0.0228  S= 33.6  N=   245.4  dN/dS=  0.1244  dN = 0.0041  dS = 0.0331
OG0022519_M0 lnL = -334.227266   t= 0.0228  S= 33.6   N=   245.4  dN/dS=  0.1244  dN = 0.0041  dS = 0.0331
OG0022519_M0 lnL = -334.227266   t= 0.0000  S= 31.7   N=   247.3  dN/dS=  0.0010  dN = 0.0000  dS = 0.0000
OG0022519_M0 lnL = -321.454615   t= 0.0000  S= 31.1   N=   247.9  dN/dS=  0.0010  dN = 0.0000  dS = 0.0000
OG0022519_M0 lnL = -325.325316  t= 0.0228  S= 33.6    N=   245.4  dN/dS=  0.1244  dN = 0.0041  dS = 0.0331
..........
...........
...........
...........
```

For the other ID's (OG******_M0) also it should do the same.
I tried this:

```
import pandas as pd

lines = []
with open("/home/Selection_Analysis/M0_res.txt", mode='r') as f:
    for line in f:
        lines.append(line.rstrip())

    res = []
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        if "OG" in lines[i] and "\\n" not in lines[i+1]:
            alignment = lines[i].split("_")[0]
    #        lnl = lines[i+1].split()[4]
    #        omega = lines[i+2].split()[3]
            dN = lines[i+3].split()[4]
            dS = lines[i+4].split()[4]
            res.append([alignment, dN, dS])
```

That code results in this error:

```
IndexError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-527c7275e76d> in <module>
      6 #        omega = lines[i+2].split()[3]
      7         dN = lines[i+3].split()[4]
----> 8         dS = lines[i+4].split()[4]
      9         res.append([alignment, dN, dS])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please explain your logic behind the parsing you want.  There are 4 `lnL` lines and 5 `t=...` lines, yet in your sample output there are 5 lines.  How are the `lnL` lines matched to the `t=...` ones?  Is it just incomplete sample data or is some logic involved?  Also I remove the bash, r and shell tags, since this is a python script.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the number of `lnL=` lines matches the number of `t=` lines for each `OG*M0` block, you could do it this way, using `awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS = " ";
    lnL_index = 0;
    values_index = 0;
    printf "ID           InL                t          S           N           dN/dS           dN           dS\n";
}
/^OG.*_M0$/ {
    for (i in lnL_array) printf "%s %s %s\n", ID, lnL_array[i], values_array[i];
    delete lnL_array;
    delete values_array;
    lnL_index = 0;
    values_index = 0;
    ID = $0;
}
/^lnL = / {
    lnL_array[lnL_index++] = $0;
}
/^ t= / {
    values_array[values_index++] = $0;
}
END {
    for (i in lnL_array) printf "%s %s %s\n", ID, lnL_array[i], values_array[i];
}
```

- Put this code in a file called `parse.awk`, and run `awk -f parse.awk INPUT_FILE.txt`
- `FS` is set to `" "` (space).
- When a `^OG.*_M0$` line is found, print the current content of the arrays (if any) and reset everything to 0.
- When a `^lnL =`  line is found, keep the line in an lnL array
- When a `^ t=`  line is found, keep the line in a values array
- To print the last `^OG.*_M0$` block, print the arrays again in the `END` section.

---

Or use an equivalent implementation in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import re

lines = []
with open("input.txt", mode='r') as f:
    for line in f:
        lines.append(line.rstrip())

print("ID           InL               t          S           N           dN/dS           dN           dS")

lnL_array = []
values_array = []

for i in lines:
    #print("line=" + i)

    if re.match(r"^OG.*_M0$", i):
        for j, lnL_value in enumerate(lnL_array):
            value = values_array[j]
            print(ID + " " + lnL_value + value )

        lnL_array.clear()
        values_array.clear()
        ID = i

    if re.match(r"^lnL = ", i):
        lnL_array.append(i.rstrip())

    if re.match(r"^ t= ", i):
        values_array.append(i.rstrip())

for j, lnL_value in enumerate(lnL_array):
    value = values_array[j]
    print(ID + " " + lnL_value + value )
```

The logic is the same as with `awk`, just with python syntax.

Notes:

- you can loop on elements without using indexes if you do not need them.  Ex. here in the main loop, you can loop on `lines` directly.
- if you have to use the indexes, use `enumerate`, like I did with index `j` to print the content of both arrays.

---

Your idea of looking ahead on line indexes is not totally wrong, but requires you to put code to check the number of elements in the arrays to stay within the index limits.  It is always better to use the language implicit loops and avoid indexes arithmetic, unless you absolutely have to (ex. in C).  Scripting languages have implicit loops on the array elements.

.